# Show element only if classname exists (with no control over value of classname)?

Tags: css

Fairly sure there isn't a pure CSS way to do this - but thought I'd ask anyway!

I'm working with some Handlebars code that looks like this:

```
<li class="person">{{ person_name }}</li>
```

What I'd like to do is only show the element if `person_name` is non-blank. The value of `person_name` can be blank, or any ASCII string.

I know I could add a column like `person_exists` in my data, set it to `show` if `person_name` is non-blank or empty otherwise,  and then do something like this:

```
<li class="person {{ person_exists }}">{{ person_name }}</li>
<style>
.person { display: none; }
.person.show { display: block; }
```

But is there any way I could show or hide these elements without having to add an extra column to my data?

Comment: rather than having an empty li hidden with css, could you not just do an if on person name and output the li? `{{#if person_name }}  <li class="person">{{ person_name }}</li> {{/if}}`

Comment: You're quite right that this would ordinarily work, but forgot to mention: I'm working in an environment that supports Handlebars variables but not conditionals!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `:empty`
(https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:empty)

```css
.person:empty {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<li class="person">Person 1</li>
<li class="person"></li>
<li class="person">Person 2</li>
```

Comment: Brilliant! Thank you :)